# How to get the length of the json object in Angular 2 template

Tags: html, json, angular, angular2-template

I have a array of json like this.

```
[
  {
    "variations": {
      "title": {
        "newValue": "test new value1",
        "oldValue": "test old value1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "variations": {
      "data": {
        "newValue": "new data",
        "oldValue": "httpold data"
      },
      "length": {
        "newValue": "48",
        "oldValue": "9.00"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

from this i want to get the length of the variations in Html and also render and values to view.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead class="table-title">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Field count</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Field Name</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Old Value</th>
                                <th class="text-center">New Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody *ngFor="let data of datas">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left" rowspan="2">{{data.variations.length}}</td>
                                <td class="text-left" rowspan="2"></td>
                                <td class="text-left" rowspan="2"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In the above code  how can i get the `length` of `variation` data. also need to render and show all the new field and old field value to the view.
can any one please help me

Comment: use `data['variations'].length`

Comment: it show like this  [object Object]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Component side :**

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

**Template Side :**

```
<tbody *ngFor="let data of datas">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left" rowspan="2">{{objectKeys(data.variations).length}}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-length)**

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _co.objectKeys is not a function

Comment: @Ajmalsha , please check the working demo; and `objectKeys = Object.keys;` put this in component

Comment: is that angular 2 or angular 4?

Comment: Angular 5 , and it will work with any `angular2/+` version as its not angular's feature its pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a simple method or getter can do the job if passed an `object`

`template.html`

```
<pre>
    {{objectKeys(obj)}}
</pre>
```

`Component.ts`

```
 obj = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'iPhone 9',
    description: 'An apple mobile which is nothing like apple',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'smartphones',
  };

  objectKeys(obj: object): string[] {
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
      return Object.keys(obj);
    }
    return [];
  }
```